# Running a console to windows form and then need to close form

Tags: c#

I have a console app that opens a windows form.
No issues there and it populates what I need it to.
The issue is I need the console app to regain control without me physically closing the windows form.
Right now the windows form takes control with application.run(xxxx) and does not return to the console.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Instead of using Application.run, just open your Form using .Show or .ShowDialog

Comment: Maybe it should not be a console app if you need to open a form

Comment: This is an endpoint for an Alexa Skill on my own computer.  Once the form is open, the Alexa Skill is still open and running, but will not do anything until I manually close the form, then it continues.  I need it close once a  new command is given.  I've tried application.close once a new command comes into the endpoint as well as hide, etc.